# How to scrape multiple elements within a specific section of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Super new to python coming from a C# background.

Inside Microsoft's wiki page,   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft,

I'm trying to scrape all the text inside the history section.

I'm curious how to go about the situation using beautiful soup. I understand that beautiful soup doesn't have XPath support.

The first element to be scraped from the history section is:

```
<div role="note" class="hatnote navigation-not-searchable">Main article: <a href="/wiki/History_of_Microsoft" title="History of Microsoft">History of Microsoft</a></div>
```

The Last element to be scraped will be:

```
<p>On January 18, 2022, Microsoft announced the acquisition of American video game developer and <a href="/wiki/Holding_company" title="Holding company">holding company</a> <a href="/wiki/Activision_Blizzard" title="Activision Blizzard">Activision Blizzard</a> in an all-cash deal worth $68.7 billion.<sup id="cite_ref-:0_150-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-:0-150">[150]</a></sup> Activision Blizzard is best known for producing franchises, including but not limited to <i><a href="/wiki/Warcraft" title="Warcraft">Warcraft</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Diablo_(series)" title="Diablo (series)">Diablo</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Call_of_Duty" title="Call of Duty">Call of Duty</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/StarCraft" title="StarCraft">StarCraft</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Candy_Crush_Saga" title="Candy Crush Saga">Candy Crush Saga</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Crash_Bandicoot" title="Crash Bandicoot">Crash Bandicoot</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Spyro" title="Spyro">Spyro the Dragon</a></i>, <i><a href="/wiki/Skylanders" title="Skylanders">Skylanders</a></i>, and <i><a href="/wiki/Overwatch_(video_game)" title="Overwatch (video game)">Overwatch</a></i>.<sup id="cite_ref-151" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-151">[151]</a></sup> Activision and Microsoft each released statements saying the acquisition was to benefit their businesses in the <a href="/wiki/Metaverse" title="Metaverse">metaverse</a>, many saw Microsoft's acquisition of video game studios as an attempt to compete against <a href="/wiki/Meta_Platforms" title="Meta Platforms">Meta Platforms</a>, with <a href="/wiki/TheStreet" title="TheStreet">TheStreet</a> referring to Microsoft wanting to become "the <a href="/wiki/The_Walt_Disney_Company" title="The Walt Disney Company">Disney</a> of the metaverse".<sup id="cite_ref-152" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-152">[152]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-153" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-153">[153]</a></sup> Microsoft has not released statements regarding Activision's recent legal controversies regarding employee abuse, but reports have alleged that Activision CEO <a href="/wiki/Bobby_Kotick" title="Bobby Kotick">Bobby Kotick</a>, a major target of the controversy, will leave the company after the acquisition is finalized.<sup id="cite_ref-154" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-154">[154]</a></sup> The deal is expected to close in 2023 followed by a review from the <a href="/wiki/US_Federal_Trade_Commission" class="mw-redirect" title="US Federal Trade Commission">US Federal Trade Commission</a>.<sup id="cite_ref-155" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-155">[155]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-:0_150-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-:0-150">[150]</a></sup>
</p>
```

How would I go about getting all the information inbetween those elements?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft'
  
# call get method to request that page
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), specifically the [sibling combinator `~`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/#general-sibling-combinator) and the [pseudo-classes](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/) `:has` and`:not`:

```py
hhSel = 'h2:has(#History)'
htSel = f'{hhSel} ~ *:not(style):not(h2):not({hhSel} ~ h2 ~ *)'
hSectTags = soup.select(htSel)

for hst in hSectTags:
    flatTxt = ' '.join(w for w in hst.get_text(' ').split() if w)
    print(hst.name, '--->', flatTxt[:100] if flatTxt else hst)
```

prints

```
div ---> Main article: History of Microsoft
link ---> <link href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1033289096" rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style"/>
div ---> For a chronological guide, see Timeline of Microsoft .
h3 ---> 1972–1985: Founding
div ---> An Altair 8800 computer (left) with the popular Model 33 ASR Teletype as terminal, paper tape reader
div ---> Paul Allen and Bill Gates on October 19, 1981, after signing a pivotal contract with IBM [11] : 228
p ---> Childhood friends Bill Gates and Paul Allen sought to make a business using their skills in computer
p ---> Microsoft entered the operating system (OS) business in 1980 with its own version of Unix called Xen
h3 ---> 1985–1994: Windows and Office
div ---> Windows 1.0 was released on November 20, 1985, as the first version of the Windows line.
p ---> Microsoft released Windows on November 20, 1985, as a graphical extension for MS-DOS, [11] : 242–243
p ---> In 1990, Microsoft introduced the Microsoft Office suite which bundled separate applications such as
p ---> On July 27, 1994, the Department of Justice's Antitrust Division filed a competitive impact statemen
h3 ---> 1995–2007: Foray into the Web, Windows 95, Windows XP, and Xbox
div ---> In 1996, Microsoft released Windows CE, a version of the operating system meant for personal digital
p ---> Following Bill Gates' internal "Internet Tidal Wave memo" on May 26, 1995, Microsoft began to redefi
div ---> Microsoft released the first installment in the Xbox series of consoles in 2001. The Xbox , graphica
p ---> On January 13, 2000, Bill Gates handed over the CEO position to Steve Ballmer , an old college frien
p ---> Increasingly present in the hardware business following Xbox, Microsoft 2006 released the Zune serie
h3 ---> 2007–2011: Microsoft Azure, Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Microsoft Stores
div ---> CEO Steve Ballmer at the MIX event in 2008. In an interview about his management style in 2005, he m
div ---> Headquarters of the European Commission, which has imposed several fines on Microsoft
p ---> Released in January 2007, the next version of Windows, Vista , focused on features, security and a r
p ---> Gates retired from his role as Chief Software Architect on June 27, 2008, a decision announced in Ju
p ---> As the smartphone industry boomed in the late 2000s, Microsoft had struggled to keep up with its riv
h3 ---> 2011–2014: Windows 8/8.1, Xbox One, Outlook.com, and Surface devices
div ---> Surface Pro 3 , part of the Surface series of laplets by Microsoft
p ---> Following the release of Windows Phone , Microsoft undertook a gradual rebranding of its product ran
p ---> In July 2012, Microsoft sold its 50% stake in MSNBC, which it had run as a joint venture with NBC si
p ---> In August 2012, the New York City Police Department announced a partnership with Microsoft for the d
div ---> The Xbox One console, released in 2013
p ---> The Kinect , a motion-sensing input device made by Microsoft and designed as a video game controller
p ---> In line with the maturing PC business, in July 2013, Microsoft announced that it would reorganize th
div ---> <div style="clear:both;"></div>
h3 ---> 2014–2020: Windows 10, Microsoft Edge, and HoloLens
div ---> Satya Nadella succeeded Steve Ballmer as the CEO of Microsoft in February 2014.
p ---> On February 4, 2014, Steve Ballmer stepped down as CEO of Microsoft and was succeeded by Satya Nadel
p ---> On January 21, 2015, Microsoft announced the release of their first Interactive whiteboard , Microso
p ---> On March 1, 2016, Microsoft announced the merger of its PC and Xbox divisions, with Phil Spencer ann
div ---> The Nokia Lumia 1320 , the Microsoft Lumia 535 and the Nokia Lumia 530 , which all run on one of the
p ---> In January 2018, Microsoft patched Windows 10 to account for CPU problems related to Intel's Meltdow
div ---> Apollo 11 astronaut Buzz Aldrin using a Microsoft HoloLens mixed reality headset in September 2016
p ---> In August 2018, Toyota Tsusho began a partnership with Microsoft to create fish farming tools using 
p ---> On February 20, 2019, Microsoft Corp said it will offer its cyber security service AccountGuard to 1
h3 ---> 2020–present: Acquisitions, Xbox Series X/S, and Windows 11
link ---> <link href="mw-data:TemplateStyles:r1033289096" rel="mw-deduplicated-inline-style"/>
div ---> Main article: Acquisition of Activision Blizzard by Microsoft
p ---> On March 26, 2020, Microsoft announced it was acquiring Affirmed Networks for about $1.35 billion. [
p ---> On July 31, 2020, it was reported that Microsoft was in talks to acquire TikTok after the Trump admi
p ---> On August 5, 2020, Microsoft stopped its xCloud game streaming test for iOS devices . According to M
p ---> On September 22, 2020, Microsoft announced that it had an exclusive license to use OpenAI ’s GPT-3 a
p ---> In April 2021, Microsoft announced it would buy Nuance Communications for approximately $16 billion.
p ---> On June 24, 2021, Microsoft announced Windows 11 during a Livestream. The announcement came with con
p ---> In October 2021, Microsoft announced that it began rolling out end-to-end encryption (E2EE) support 
p ---> On January 18, 2022, Microsoft announced the acquisition of American video game developer and holdin
```